# Which vehicles are available on which multiplayer maps in Halo 1?

Tags: halo-combat-evolved

Specifically, I would like to know on which maps the Banshee is available, but a list of the maps and the vehicles available on each would be ideal. This is for the PC version.

Comment: Halo PC or Halo Xbox?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Banshees are available on Blood Gulch, Death Island, Gephyrophobia, Infinity, and Sidewinder.

Here is a list of maps and the vehicles found therein:

- Battle Creek: None
- Blood Gulch: Banshee, Ghost, Rocket Warthog, Scorpion, Warthog
- Boarding Action: None
- Chill Out: None
- Chiron: None
- Damnation: None
- Danger Canyon: Ghost, Rocket Warthog, Scorpion, Warthog
- Death Island: Banshee, Ghost, Scorpion, Rocket Warthog, Shade, Warthog
- Derelict: None
- Gephyrophobia: Banshee, Ghost, Warthog
- Hang 'em High: None
- Ice Fields: Ghost, Scorpion, Warthog
- Infinity: Banshee, Ghost, Rocket Warthog, Shade, Warthog
- Longest: None
- Prisoner: None
- Rat Race: None
- Sidewinder: Banshee, Ghost, Scorpion, Shade, Rocket Warthog, Warthog
- Timberland: Ghost, Rocket Warthog, Scorpion, Warthog
- Wizard: None

Some of these I could remember off the top of my head, the rest I consulted [this list of multiplayer maps.](http://halo.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Halo:_Combat_Evolved_Multiplayer_Maps)  I tried to include the differences in the PC version of the game, but corrections are welcome as I was primarily a Xbox player :)